# Get selected rows first column value in datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

```
$('.example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (){
    var id = this.id;
    var index = $.inArray(id, selected);
    if (index === -1) 
    {
    selected.push(id);
    } else 
    {
    selected.splice(index, 1);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
$('#btn').click(function (){
    var dataArr = [];
    var rowCount = table.rows('.selected').data().length;
    alert(rowCount);
});
```

Here is the code for select multiple rows. On clicking the button I need to get the selected rows first column value and store in array dataArr[]. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: usually, one of the option $("#"+this.id td:first-child).html();

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/uuag2oh0/2/)**

```
$('#btn').click(function (){
    var dataArr = [];
    $.each($("#example tr.selected"),function(){ //get each tr which has selected class
        dataArr.push($(this).find('td').eq(0).text()); //find its first td and push the value
        //dataArr.push($(this).find('td:first').text()); You can use this too
    });
    console.log(dataArr);
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

You can get using some native functions of `dataTables` too as below:

```
$('#btn').click(function (){
    var dataArr = [];
    var rows = $('tr.selected');
    var rowData = table.rows(rows).data();
    $.each($(rowData),function(key,value){
        dataArr.push(value["name"]); //"name" being the value of your first column.
    });
    console.log(dataArr);
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/uuag2oh0/3/)**

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: I have similar requirement but in my case my ID is hidden "bVisible": false? so how can I get the hidden column value of the selected row?

Comment: @GhostRider.. You need to ask separate question specifying the exact requirement... :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: Here is the link to my question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34869730/datatables-editor-filed-type-select-action-for-edit-and-remove-buttons-issues

Answer (score 1):

Guruprasad code (perfect) with small handy updates.

```
var table= $('#YourTableName').DataTable();
$('#button').click(function () {
           var arr = [];
           $.each(table.rows('.selected').data(), function() {
               arr.push(this["ColomnName"]);
           });
});
```