# Apply format function to all table rows based on column tag in JS

Tags: javascript, datatables

I would like to define a column formatter based on the header tag.

As a simple example, if I have in the header of the table:

```
<th data-formatter="roundTo4dp">4 Decimal Place Rounded Numbers</th>
<th data-formatter="roundTo0dp">0 Decimal Place Rounded Numbers</th>
```

I need some JS/JQuery code that calls and applies the 'data-formatter' function (defined elsewhere) to each row of that column.

I have seen some posts that consider getting all cells from a column ([Datatable get the values of all rows of a specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53221439/datatable-get-the-values-of-all-rows-of-a-specific-column)) but I cannot see how I iterate of those cells and apply the function name extracted from the data-formatter parameter.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Ultimately, I am just trying to display a datatable that has dates, and a number of different number formats required within the one table (0dp, 2dp and 4dp) so I need to format each column a little differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use columns render in order to get the formatter and run it when defined:

```js
function roundTo4dp(data) {
    return parseFloat(data).toFixed(4);
}
function roundTo0dp(data) {
    return parseFloat(data).toFixed(0);
}

$('#myTable').DataTable({
    columns: [
        {data: 'Name'},
        {data: 'Position'},
        {data: 'Office'},
        {data: 'Age',
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                var formatter = $(meta.settings.nTHead).find('th').eq(meta.col).data('formatter');
                return (formatter == undefined ? data : window[formatter](data));
            }},
        {data: 'Start date'},
        {
            data: 'Salary',
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                var formatter = $(meta.settings.nTHead).find('th').eq(meta.col).data('formatter');
                return (formatter == undefined ? data : window[formatter](data));
            }
        }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="myTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th data-formatter="roundTo0dp">Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th data-formatter="roundTo4dp">Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>372,000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```